# Kendo UI - Templating a list of checkboxes and binding checked to viewModel

Tags: javascript, mvvm, kendo-ui, telerik

I have a template for a checkbox row -- I set a value when I render the template, but the MVVM checked binding throws an exception. I'm confused as to why this doesn't work as the generated code is pretty much an example given by kendo itself (http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/mvvm/elements)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled</title>

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.716/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
  <script id="fTemplate" type="text/html">
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" value="#=data#" data-bind="checked: selectedF"/>
        <div style="display: inline-block; margin-left: 5px;">#=data#</div>
    </div>
   </script>

   <script>
     var viewModel = window.kendo.observable({
       fSource: ["1","2","3"],
       selectedF: [],
       selectedFText: function(){
            return viewModel.get('selectedF').join(',');
       }

     });

     $(document).ready(function() {
       window.kendo.bind($('body'), viewModel);
     });


  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <ul data-bind="source: fSource" data-template="fTemplate"></ul>
  <br/>
  Selected: <div data-bind="text: selectedFText"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Live example here: http://dojo.telerik.com/EMIp

Comment: My first guess is because you bind on fSource, your list and fSource doesn't know what is selectedF.

I'm looking for a complete solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because you try to access a property of a viewModel that your template doesn't know.

Here is an example that is working. I'm pretty sure it will give you enough to help you.

```
<script id="fTemplate" type="text/html">
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" value="#=data.value#" data-bind="checked: isSelected"/>
        <div style="display: inline-block; margin-left: 5px;">#=data.value#</div>
    </div>
</script>

<script>
     var viewModel = window.kendo.observable({
       fSource: [
         {
            value:"1",
            isSelected: false
         },
         {
            value:"2",
            isSelected: false
         },
         {
            value:"3",
            isSelected: false
         }],
       selectedF: [],
       selectedFText: function(){
       }
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
       window.kendo.bind($('body'), viewModel);
    });
</script>
```

Html:

```
 <body>
  <ul data-bind="source: fSource" data-template="fTemplate"></ul>
  <br/>
  Selected: <div data-bind="text: fSource[0].isSelected"></div>
</body>
```

your fiddle:

http://dojo.telerik.com/EMIp/5